# Should text pre-processing come before or after POS-tagging?

Tags: data-mining, natural-language

I am currently working on an assignment to produce a sentiment classifier for Twitter. One of the initial, and most important, stages in NLP classification is text pre-processing. For Twitter, this includes steps such as the following:

1. Removing (or not) Twitter mentions
2. Removing (or not) URLs
3. Dealing with capitalised text
4. Dealing with hashtags

and more. One of the pre-processing/feature extraction steps is POS-tagging, whereby a grammatical word-type is assigned to each word in a text (in this case a tweet).

One thing I am unsure of is whether to POS tag and then do the pre-processing steps (such as those described above) or whether to pre-process and then POS tag.

I intend to use the GATE POS-tagger, which is trained on Twitter data, and can be found here: https://gate.ac.uk/wiki/twitter-postagger.html

**POS-tagging --> pre-processing**

The reason I would consider doing this way round is because I imagine that a POS-tagger performs better on fully-provided text (i.e. how a tweet appears before being pre-processed). The disadvantage in doing this is that it makes pre-processing more difficult. For example, getting rid of Twitter mentions would become more difficult than just applying a simple regex command to each tweet, partly because the POS-tagger will likely tokenise the '@name' into '@' and 'name'.

**Pre-processing --> POS-tagging**

This would make the process quicker and easier. However, as mentioned above, it is of my intuition that a POS-tagger might behave more poorly on a pre-processed text.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

If answering this, perhaps it is a good idea to discuss this problem for both normal text and Twitter, and whether or not the POS-tagger is trained on Twitter data. This would be more beneficial for people stumbling across this question in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time, the pre-processing phase is done to normalize or canonize the structure of the text. Hence, to get a stable result, it can have more advantages to applying pre-process first, and pos-tagging then.

On the other hand, to get your decision on this issue, you should measure pros and cons of each method. As you are working on tweets, removed elements in the pre-processing phase have not a viable role in the pos-tagging most of the times. Hence, pre-processing to get a canonical form of tweets could have more advantages on POS-tagging, than POS-tagging on pre-processing.